# What's the scope of `ufw` and its implicit Deny rule with regards to my network?

Tags: networking, firewall, ufw

Is the implicit deny of UFW only for when people are connecting to its IP address or for the whole network? I have tried telnet to the IP address and yes it gets denied but when I tried to telnet to another IP in the network it was able to connect shouldn't it be denied as well?

Comment: The implicit deny is on the inbound direction, I believe, from other systems to the machine with the implicit deny.

Comment: So only up to the machine and not the network? Is there a way to make it for everything?

Comment: Because my current setup is 2 ubuntu systems and 1 windows xp with all of their ip addresses in the same network. One ubuntu system has the UFW. The windows xp gets denied when I use the telnet service on the ubuntu system with UFW however I am able to access the other ubuntu system. So my question is is it possible to make the implicit deny for the whole network?

Comment: My answer below is huge, but it thoroughly analyzes your options, and explains for the most part where your confusion exists, and explains to you the breakdown of your network.  It also provides an example of my network to explain how you could achieve that, however in a very expensive way.

Comment: I've also reread your question with your comments, and have updated the title to indicate that you're asking the scope of coverage of `ufw` (i.e. "is it one computer or the entire network the rule affects" being the effective question)

Answer (score 1):

Based on your comments, I think you've failed to understand what `ufw` is, and what the scope of coverage is for software firewalls on individual systems.

---

This is a breakdown of the situation, and provides insight into the specifics of `ufw` and the rules on a network:

- `ufw` will only affect one system - the system it's enabled on.  That is to say, Ubuntu System #1 (for sake of keeping track) has `ufw` enabled with an implicit deny rule.  That only affects Ubuntu System #1, and replaces the default "ACCEPT" rule that exists on the underlying `iptables`/`netfilter` system (of which `ufw` is just a 'easy to manage' front end for).
- Since Ubuntu System #2 does not have `ufw` enabled on it, there is no "deny" rule on it.  Since `ufw` isn't there, the underlying `iptables`/`netfilter` system gets the default "ACCEPT" rule that is put in place on install (`ufw` changes those rules, and is just an 'easy to manage' front end for those).
- Windows Firewall on Windows XP (if enabled) will be able to deny connections to the Windows machine.  It cannot affect other systems on the network

If you want Ubuntu System #2 to have the deny rule, install `ufw` on that system, enable it, and then the implicit deny rule will exist.

---

What you want, though,  is a network-wide access control rule, controlling what traffic is permitted **between** systems.  The only way to achieve this is to move the firewall and network controls to its own device, a separate Ubuntu box handling routing of traffic between all systems on your network, or a hardware Firewall to achieve this (such as a Cisco ASA, or a pfSense appliance).

Consider the following network:

I have a LAN network, and there's a router handling connections out from LAN to Internet (or other networks).  Every computer has 192.168.252.XXX, with static addressing.  Five computers are on that segment of the network.  I want to restrict communication between the machines to be `ICMP PING` packets only, and apply that restriction to all machines.

My options for implementation are as follows:

- Install software firewalls on each machine, and configure the software firewalls to accept only certain types of traffic from the other machines on the network to each computer.  However, allow all traffic between each system and the gateway/router.
- Install a hardware firewall that suits your network setups to replace the router, and provide explicit rule definition for permitted intra-network traffic (internal to the specific LAN) and inter-network traffic (communication between networks, so outside your LAN).  Configure as follows

  - Configure the hardware firewall to allow outbound to the Internet (a rule basically saying Anything Internal -> Anything Not Internal (NOT 192.168.252.0/24) is ALLOWED).
  - Configure the hardware firewall for the LAN itself for ALLOWED inter-system traffic, in this case ICMP only (a rule basically saying anything from 192.168.252.0/24 to 192.168.252.0/24 where the protocol is ICMP).
  - Any traffic patterns that do not match aforementioned rules is automatically denied.
- Replace the router with an Ubuntu box with enough ethernet ports to provide enough connections for your network and Wireless if you need it, configure it to do DHCP, NAT, etc., and configure the firewall rules on the Ubuntu box to handle traffic both inside and outside the network (similar to previous).

---

To provide you with another point of view, though, which drives this answer, my network at home has a lot of LAN segments (as VLANs, or Virtual LANs).  I use a hardware firewall (a pfSense appliance, $500ish) to handle the VLANs on my network (DHCP, NAT out to the Internet, etc.), as well as inter-communication rules between the segments, which restrict access.  Machines I actively use exist on one VLAN, whereas restricted-access machines exist on a separate VLAN and network range.  Communication to those is restricted by a rule on both sides which dictates what traffic is permitted to pass between the segments.  Essentially, this is the second option from above, implemented in a much more advanced way.

Comment: Oh ok I understand but for example if I deny port 80 (http) on a certain IP that computer with that IP won't be able to access certain websites right?

Comment: @user3435500 No, you have two directions for traffic: INBOUND and OUTBOUND.  The rule you have to deny Telnet is for "INBOUND" traffic to "Ubuntu System #1".  All other systems will still be able to communicate otherwise.  If the rule were put into the "OUTBOUND" rules for any one system to deny Port 80, then that system would not be able to reach http sites.  If your rule is on US#1 to "ALLOW 80 INBOUND" then that accepts any traffic heading TO that box on port 80, and then responds accordingly where the OUTBOUND rules permit.

Comment: So for example if I want my windows XP to not be able to access any http sites what command must i perform on UFW?

Comment: @user3435500 You still fail to understand the scope of `ufw`.  ***`ufw` only applies to the machine it is installed on.***  It has **zero effect** on the traffic patterns of other computers, it merely controls the rules for the system it is installed on, and that's all.  To control the traffic on your Windows XP box, you have to configure the Windows firewall, or put a firewall appliance on your network that can make rulesets that affect multiple networked systems at once (which would include your WinXP and Ubuntu boxes)

Comment: Oh ok I see would you happen to know if FirewallD can support the whole network?

Comment: @user3435500 Any **software firewall** will only affect the system it's installed on, unless that server is configured to route all the traffic for the network around.  As such, I can't say whether FirewallD will or won't support the network because one computer in your likely setup (i assume you have *one router* that handles all the connections for your network) won't be able to affect traffic on the entire network.  You have to control traffic at the router, essentially, as it handles routing of data to/from computers on the network to/from other systems and the internet.